# Find records where a timestamp is present

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQL, and the following query is not working anymore:

```
where("my_timestamp is NOT NULL and my_timestamp != ''")
```

How can I find all records that have a certain (datetime) attribute present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `my_timestamp` column is a real `timestamp` (i.e. `t.datetime` in ActiveRecord parlance) then a simple NOT NULL test is sufficient:

```
where('my_timstamp is not null')
```

If this is the case then your query should be giving you an error like:

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
```

pointing at your `my_timestamp != ''` test. Your comparison with an empty string worked fine in SQLite because SQLite doesn't have a real timestamp type, it just uses ISO 8601 formatted strings in text columns; this data type problem is also why you ended up with `''` in your timestamp columns in SQLite in the first place.